# Confirm-Box asking me endless times

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I always getting ask endless times if I am *really* sure that I want to delete the file. I don't know why this event fires multiple times.

I am using backbone.js.

This is my View (shortened). On click "span.delete" it fires the remove function (it's working flawlessly).

```js
XFFView = Backbone.View.extend({
        itemTpl: _.template($("#xff-item").html()),
        events: {
            "click span.delete" : "remove"
        },
        remove: function() {
                 app.delFromList(this.$el.children('li').data('target'));
                 this.$el.remove();
        } 
});
```

And this is the delFromList function, that's firing the confirm request. I get asked again and again and again, until I click on 'cancel'.

```js
delFromList: function(id) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this file?')) {
                this.collection.get(id).destroy();
        }
},
```

Comment: Could you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) reproducing the issue?

Comment: Pretty much impossible due to backbone.js overhead. It would take me hours to reproduce it accordingly. But could it be because there's no prevenDefault? How do I use e.preventDefault in the delFromList function without passing the event as argument (instead of id)?

Comment: you could reduce the scope of it to isolate and replicate the issue alone. Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/thomas/C9wew/4/). I can't replicate it based off that, there is a collection and one view, there is usually a parent view and a per item view which I cannot see. I also cannot see which events you are listening to

Comment: Couldn't reproduce it myself, lol. But after replacing this.collection.get(id).destroy(); with console.debug("test"), this loop does not appear anymore. So it have to with this.collection.get(id).destroy(). However, these are basic backbone functions and it just destroys the obj from the collection. Not sure where to look now.

Comment: If removing that stops the issue then look at the views, do you have any code like  'this.model.on('change', this.remove, this);'?. It looks like the remove function is somehow attached to model destroy event too

Comment: Not sure if this is gonna help, but here's the (nearly) full-size XFFView http://pastebin.com/uF2iH9Wr and the AppView (which is really messy) http://pastebin.com/ptS63TyV If you see something unusual, I would be glad if you could help me. But please don't mind the coding style, I know there are some don'ts in this mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beleive I have found your issue, it was as I expected:

```
XFFView = Backbone.View.extend({
            itemTpl: _.template($("#xff-item").html()),
            events: {
                    "click span.delete" : "remove",
                    "click span.abort" : "abort"
            },
            initialize: function() {
                    this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
                    this.listenTo(this.model, "destroy", this.remove);
            },
            render: function() {
                    this.$el.html(this.itemTpl(this.model.toJSON()));
                    return this;
            },
            remove: function() {
                    app.delXFFFromList(this.$el.children('li').children('span.delete.badge').data('target'));
                    this.$el.remove();
            }
```

From what I can tell, this line:

```
this.listenTo(this.model, "destroy", this.remove);
```

is listening for the model to be removed, which it is in this line:

```
this.collection.get(id).destroy();
```

Which will then call this code again:

```
remove: function() {
       app.delXFFFromList(this.$el.children('li').children('span.delete.badge').data('target'));
       this.$el.remove();
}
```

Basically throwing your code into an infinite loop, or until your collection empties.

Either change this line

```
this.listenTo(this.model, "destroy", this.remove);
```

to call this.destroy, OR rename your remove method to something like removeEntry so that it does not get confused with removal of the view.

Comment: Good catch, I honestly didn't see that. Thanks a lot!